# rails twitter_oauth library uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, twitter, rubygems

I'm trying to use the twitter_oauth gem : http://github.com/moomerman/twitter_oauth

In my model I have:

```
require 'twitter_oauth'
```

And within a function I have:

```
def example
   client = TwitterOAuth::Client.new(
   :consumer_key => 'xxxx',
   :consumer_secret => 'xxxx',
   :token => "xxxx", 
   :secret => "xxxx")
   return client
end
```

This seems fairly straight forward, but I can't seem to find out why I'm getting this error:

(Event being the name of the model)

**uninitialized constant Event::TwitterOAuth**

I can't seem to locate any conflicts with the TwitterOAuth namespace, any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to use Grackle instead, seems to work fine